# Javascript - async await doesn't work with conditional

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, vue.js, async-await, vuejs2

I've been working on it for several hours and I'm still more and more confused about how async/await works. Right now I have this code:

```
    created: function () {

         Event.$on('open-stage', (stage) => {

            this.$validator.validateAll().then(() => {

                const validateFields = async () => {
                    const uniqueEmail = await this.checkIfUniqueEmail();
                    if(uniqueEmail) {
                       console.log('uniqueEmail is true'); // <-- this is what I need to achieve
                       Event.$emit('change-stage', this.wizardStage.successor);
                    }
                };

                validateFields();
            }).catch(() => {
                toastr.warning('Error');
                Event.$emit('change-stage-denied');
                return true;
            });
        });
    },

    methods: {
        checkIfUniqueEmail() {
            if (!this.player.email || !this.player.email.length) {
                return true;
            }

            this.$http.post('playerExists', {
                email: this.player.email
            }).then(response => {
                if (response.data.exists) {
                    toastr.error(Good');
                    Event.$emit('change-stage-denied');
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }).catch(error => {
                toastr.warning('Fail');
                Event.$emit('change-stage-denied');
                return false;
            });
        },
    }
```

My goal is simple - if method `checkIfUniqueEmail()` returns true I want to see console.log and will emit `change-state`. The problem is that constant `uniqueEmail` is always undefined. How can I make this only after response from function `checkIfUniqueEmail()` is true? What I need to change? I'm using vue.js 2.1.10.

Comment: `checkIfUniqueEmail` needs to be an `async` function to be able to use it along with `await`. [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: Uh, your `checkIfUniqueEmail` method doesn't `return` the promise - returning inside the `then` callback alone is not enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your method return the promise

```
checkIfUniqueEmail() {
    if (!this.player.email || !this.player.email.length) {
        return true;
    }

    return this.$http.post('playerExists', {
        email: this.player.email
    }).then(response => {
        if (response.data.exists) {
            toastr.error('Good');
            Event.$emit('change-stage-denied');
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }).catch(error => {
        toastr.warning('Fail');
        Event.$emit('change-stage-denied');
        return false;
    });
}
```

Comment: No, you don't *need* to make it `async` - returning the promise is enough. But when you do, you should probably let go of `then` and `catch` and use `await` as proper.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this:

```js
    async function validateFields() {
      var uniqueEmail = await checkIfUniqueEmail();
        if(uniqueEmail) {
          console.log('uniqueEmail is true'); 
        }  
    }
    
    function checkIfUniqueEmail(){
      return new Promise(resolve => {
       setTimeout(() => {
          resolve('johny@bravo.com');
        }, 1000)
      })
    }
    
    validateFields();
```

The above, actually represents your situation, so considering this simple example it is clear that simply returning a resolved Promise is a possible way to go. So you can just do something like:

```
this.$http.post('playerExists', {
    email: this.player.email
}).then(response => {
    if (response.data.exists) {
        toastr.error('Good');
        Event.$emit('change-stage-denied');
        return new Promise(resolve => {
           resolve(true)
        };
    }
<...>
```